# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined in ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, angular5

I faced a problem that every time I change my code an error occured :

```
1) Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined => core.js

2)Cannot read property 'call' of undefined => module-loader.js
```

so i have to do "ionic serve" everytime i change the code to remove the error.
so i waste lot of times.
can anyone know what's the problem?

- ionic CLI 4.0.2
- ionic-angular: "3.9.2",
- angular/core: "5.0.0",

Comment: Ionic Cli 4 supports Angular 6. May be you can delete node_modules fodler and do npm install and launch it.

Comment: why should i delete the node_modules, and if i remove it and then npm install what will change?

Comment: Might be your node Modules dependency mismatch and due to this it may cause error. just have a try

Comment: can i decrease the version of cli ?

Comment: you should use latest ionic version which will have performance improvement, latest angular support etc.

Comment: yes i think it works. hope i don't discover new issues because of deleting the node_modules

Answer (score 1):

If you are running multiple ionic serve on same machine then this error can come.

Try close all CMD windows and then start new CMD in your project folder and then do ionic serve

Answer (score 0):

Hope, deleting the node_modules from your project codebase and doing npm install again solves your problem. Keep Learning.

Comment: You need to remove node_modules and try again. Might be there is an issue with npm from your end.

Comment: i did, same problem

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + c 
after yes 
after

> ionic serve again

all will be fine 
it work for me

Comment: i do this with every change of single caracter .

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually the result of running multiple ionic serve at the same time.

Comment: not actually. i close everythink and re-run and when i change any single character in code , the error come again

Comment: Joe, I was simply stating when I have encountered this error the source was "ionic serve" running in a different terminal window.

Comment: But in my case it isn't

Comment: What have u tried? Have you attempted to install a clean build of your project on a different device? Maybe cut a new branch of your project and roll back to a previous version that did not have this issue.

Comment: I can't back to previous version there's a lot of changes and many branches developed after this error... and till now i have to do ionic serve on every single caracter change